# Как сказать "первые 20 строк", только для 21?

Tags: грамматика

"Первая двадцать одна строка"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Правильно:

> *перв**ые** двадцать одна строка, перв**ые** тридцать один день.*

Comment: А ПОЧЕМУ именно ТАК правильно?! На сайте (в разделе — "Как дать правильный ответ?") написано: аргументируйте свой ответ примерами и ссылками. И где хоть что-нибудь из указанного (рекомендуемого)?